# How do i create a notification in a fragment in android

Tags: android, notifications, fragment

I am trying to create a notification in a fragment. I am having errors. Can any help ?

Here is my code

```
NotificationManager notification = (Notification) getSystemService(getActivity().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
CharSequence tickerText = "your daily tip";
long when System.currentTimeMillis();
Context context = getActivity();
CharSequence contentTitle = "AutoKit";
CharSequence = contentText = "hi";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contextTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

The error lies in the first line.

Comment: You are trying to cast a `NotificationManager` into a `Notification`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your first line with this one, should do the trick :

```
NotificationManager notification = ( NotificationManager ) getActivity().getSystemService( getActivity().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sendNotifications(String user,String msg){
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel1",
            "hello",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)requireActivity().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    //Creating the notification object
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(requireContext(), "channel1");
    notification.setContentTitle("New message from " + user);
    notification.setContentText(msg);
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
}
```